# How to write a macro loop over months in YYYYMM format?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have 26 tables in my SAS work folder that goes with yearMONTH format that goes from 201301-201502 (i.e. 201301 to 201312, 201401 to 201412, 201501, 201502). I have to create 26 new tables, and join them (see sample code below for more details).

How should I loop the data? I was planning to use a marco, but wasn't quite sure how to loop it. Also, I believe there could be better a way than using a macro.

```
%Macro YearMonth(YM=  );

PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.Join&YM AS 
   SELECT t1.ID, 
      t1.Eff_YM, 
      t1.Trm_YM 

  FROM WORK.DATASET_&YM AS t1 
        LEFT JOIN Work.Names AS t2 
            AND ( input(t1.YearMonth, 6.) = t2.Paid_End_dt2j);
QUIT;
%mend;
%YearMonth(YM = 201301) 
....
%YearMonth(YM = 201502)
```

Comment: Why do you have 26 tables??  How many observations in your dataset?  Can you not append into one dataset?

Comment: I have seen the same partitioning pattern in old data warehouse solutions as well,. One possible explanation might be lack of good partition support of large data sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comment, vol7ron asks an important question:

> Why do you have 26 tables?? How many observations in your dataset? Can you not append into one dataset?

Having a separate data set for each month suggests a problematic design upstream.  However, let's assume that's out of your control.  One very simple way to iterate over the months via a macro loop is the following:

```
%macro loop(start_month=, stop_month=);
    %local month;
    %do month=&start_month %to &stop_month;
        %put Month: &month;

        %* SQL CODE HERE....

        %* SPECIAL CASE WHEN WE REACH END OF A YEAR;
        %if %substr(&month, 5, 2) = 12 %then %let month = %eval(&month + 88);       
    %end;
%mend loop;

%loop(start_month=200301, stop_month=201502)
```

Notice the placeholder for your SQL code.  This basic template would work for any similar situation, however.  The key is the last line before the `%end` statement, which increments the loop variable by 88 so that it goes from (for example) 201312 to 201400.  Then, control reaches the top of the `%do` loop, where `&month` is incremented to 201401.  Thus, if on some iteration `&month` equals 201312, then on the next iteration it will equal 201401.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes differing from Matthew's generally sound answer.

First off, I highly recommend writing your sql code in a separate macro from the one that does the looping (if you even use a macro for that).  It makes testing easier, and modifications easier, and is generally good programming practice.  So if you go the route of a macro loop, where Matthew has `%* PUT SQL CODE HERE;`, actually call the other macro that you've already written.

Second, while the macro-loop approach is fine and sometimes is the right approach, a somewhat more easily maintained method is to call your macro from the data rather than a macro loop.  This is what I do with probalby 95% of my code.

This will be clearly superior in the following circumstances:

1. You already have a dataset with the 26 months stored as a variable (26 observations, one per month).  Doesn't have to be primarily for this purpose - just if it already exists somewhere.
2. You have just these 26 datasets already (and not others that you don't want) in a libname somewhere, where either they're the only datasets, or the only ones named like they are (more common).

It can also be used in other circumstances - it's very easy to make the dataset like 1 above, somewhat easier than the macro loop - but it doesn't necessarily add in those cases.

Let's say you have 2) - you have `DATASET_201301` to `DATASET_201412` in the WORK library, and nothing else is titled `DATASET_`.  Then you can use `dictionary.tables` like so:

```
proc sql;
  select cats('%YearMonth(ym=',scan(memname,2,'_'),')')
    into :callyears separated by ' '
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname='WORK' and memname like 'DATASET_%'
  ;
quit;
&callyears.
```

That creates a macro variable, `&callyears.`, which stores the text from the select - in this case, macro calls that we've created using the concatenation function `cats`.  `memname` is a dataset name, and `libname` of course is a libname.

This is a fairly simple way to call a macro using a data-driven approach; this means that the next time you need to run this, you don't have to change anything in your code here - as long as the code before this which creates the 26 datasets pulls the 26 new datasets (or however many!), you're good to go.  And if you add a 27th or 28th, it will automatically pull those also.  You could include something in the `where` statement to filter things out, of course - `where libname='WORK' and memname like 'DATASET_%' and scan(memname,2,'_') ge '201301'` for example.